# need some help on awk command

Tags: unix, awk

need a help with awk. reading a csv file and, doing some substitution on some of the columns. It's like 9th column(string type) should be replaced by value of (9th column itself + value of the 4th column(integer)), then 15th column by $15+$12, column 26th with $26+$23. same has to be done line by line for all the records. Suggestions please

Below is the sample I/O. and the first line which is Description must be left as is.

**sample Input**

```
EmpID|Empname|Empadd|roleId|roleDesc|Dept 
100|mst|Del|20|SD|DA 
101|ms|Del|21|XS|DA
```

**Sample output**

```
EmpID|Empname|Empadd|roleId|roleDesc|Dept 
100|mst100|Del|20|SD20|DA
101|ms101|Del|21|XS21|DA
```

it's like empname has been concatenated with empid & the role desc with roleID.Hope that's helpful :)

---

Comment: `awk '$9=$9$4; $15+=$12; ...`

Comment: Are all those columns integers? You should give some data examples for that.

Comment: Show some representative sample input and expected output. And you do not need to literally have 26+ columns in REPRESENTATIVE input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will perform the needed transformation:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{$2=$2$1;$5=$5$4}1' FS='|' OFS='|' file
EmpID|Empname|Empadd|roleId|roleDesc|Dept 
100|mst100|Del|20|SD20|DA
101|ms101|Del|21|XS21|DA
```

If you have to do this for many columns you can use a `for` loop like so (provided a arithmetic or geometric stepsize):

```
$ awk 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=5;i+=3)$i=$i$(i-1)}1' FS='|' OFS='|' file
EmpID|Empname|Empadd|roleId|roleDesc|Dept 
100|mst100|Del|20|SD20|DA
101|ms101|Del|21|XS21|DA
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say `+`, I'm assuming you mean string concatentation. IN awk, there is no specific concatenation operator, you just put two strings side-by-side.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$9 = $9 $4; $15=$15$12; $26=$26$23; print}' file.csv
```

Also assuming that by "csv", you actually mean comma-separated.

If you want to edit the file in-place, you need to do this:

```
awk  ... file.csv > newfile && mv file.csv file.csv.bak && mv newfile file.csv
```

---

**Edit**: to leave the first line untouched:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR>1 {$9 = $9 $4; $15=$15$12; $26=$26$23} {print}' file.csv
```

Now the columns are modified for the 2nd and subsequent lines, but every line is printed.
You'll sometimes see that written this way:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR>1 {$9 = $9 $4; $15=$15$12; $26=$26$23} 1' file.csv
```

Comment: I just forgot to mention that first line,which holds the description of fields,has to be left as is.